# Is Bluetooth smart supported? If so, how; if not yet, when?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I've seen a couple of questions relating to users wanting to use their Logitech MX Anywhere 2 Bluetooth mouse with Ubuntu. I am in the same boat. I eagerly awaited the release of Ubuntu 15.10 because there had been some advice that our mouse would be supported in this release. Unfortunately I can't find that it is. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong -- any suggestions? Perhaps it's coming later? If that's the case, which release are we looking to now.

Thanks very much,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

BlueZ 4 (ubuntu bluetooth manager) version on earlier versions of Ubuntu didn't have support for Bluetooth Smart and therefore Logitech MX Anywhere 2 mouse couldn't work but Ubuntu 15.10 comes with BlueZ 5.35 version that supports Bluetooth Smart and Logitech MX Anywhere 2 mouse should work on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: On my new install of Ubuntu 15.10, my new Logitech MX Anywhere 2 mouse is not even found during Bluetooth search. Under version 15.04 the mouse was found and prperly identified; but as you say, not supported under 15.04. Please if you canhelp me figure out how to make this work, I'd be grateful -- for me, it doesn't "just work out-of-the-box."  Thanks for any constructive suggestions.

Comment: You can try and install `sudo apt-get install blueman`, (Blueman Bluetooth interface) an app that manages bluetooth and try with it or try using terminal.

Comment: Type `bluetoothctl` in to the terminal where you'll get an interface to interact with Bluetooth devices. Type `help` to get a list of commands and what they do. The command that you'll want to use first for pairing the MX Anywhere 2 is the `scan` command. If you type `scan on`, your computer will start searching for Bluetooth devices.

Comment: While in this mode, put your MX Anywhere 2 in to pairing mode and wait for it to show up in the console. It will show up something like this: `[NEW] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX MX Anywhere 2 (The name may not be accurate)
` The "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" string is the MAC address of your MX Anywhere 2. To pair it and connect it, type: `pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` `connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` Make sure to change all the "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" to the MAC address you got when scanning.

Comment: The answer and guide is taken from this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/636712/logitech-mx-anywhere-2-mouse-pairs-but-doesnt-do-anything

Comment: All well and good. Now the mouse is recognized and paired. But when I try to connect Bluetooth crashes. If I get Bluetooth up the mouse disconnects. So, bottom line is the mouse still doesn't work with Ubuntu. If I can figure out how to uninstall Ubuntu, I'll give fedora a try. After that, Apple . . .?

Comment: You can download Fedora from the official site `https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/`. Create installation USB using Startup Disk Creator app or write it on CD in Ubuntu and choose to install alongside or delete Ubuntu. I've seen posts  of other people using Logitech MX Anywhere 2 and it's working for them on Fedora. It's on you to try it out.

Comment: You can search for installation guides or videos online,ask in another post or ask me over chat and I'll reply as soon as i can.