# Ubuntu 15.10, logitech mx anywhere mouse pairs but doesn't do anything

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth, logitech

When I used Ubuntu 15.04 with bluez5 from PPA installed, the mouse works. But after installing Ubuntu 15.04, the mouse doesn't work.

```
[bluetooth]# info XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Name: MX Anywhere 2
Alias: MX Anywhere 2
Icon: input-mouse
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: yes
LegacyPairing: no
```

bluez5 have already included in ubuntu 15.10. 
The mouse paring and connecting seem fine but the mouse doesn't do anything.

```
$dpkg -l | grep bluez
ii  bluez                                         5.35-0ubuntu2                              amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
```

Comment: I have the same question. Bought this bluetooth mouse and can not use it with my brand new ultrabook running Kubuntu 15.10.
It's connected and all seems fine, but just nothing happens.

Comment: Does it work under Windows/on other machines?

Comment: Does using the PPA bluez5 package that you referenced on 15.10 instead of the default install one make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

In a related thread the user Tobi just updated his answer for Ubuntu 15.10, which worked for me perfectly: [Logitech MX Anywhere 2 mouse pairs but doesn't do anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636712/logitech-mx-anywhere-2-mouse-pairs-but-doesnt-do-anything)

In fact the PIN-less pairing method of the MX Anywhere 2 is not very well implemented in Ubuntu 15.10.
This commands have to be run to make the pairing work:

```
hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
hciconfig hci0 down
hciconfig hci0 up
```