# Logitech MX Master Wireless Mouse under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, bluetooth, logitech, logitech-unifying

I've attempted to find a thread on this but can'y seem to find anything specific to whether this Logitech MX Master Wireless Mouse works under Ubuntu 14.04 - unifying and Bluetooth Smart?

See: http://www.logitech.com/en-au/product/mx-master

If some body can confirm that it does/doesn't under Ubuntu 14.04 or if I need to actually install any packages inorder to make it work, pls let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: works perfectly fin with 14.04 LTS... In fact I just upgraded from a Performance MX (my second one) that had worn out.... these are fantastic mice. Get a program called SOLAAR - well worth using that wiht the Logitech receiver to pair and monitor multiple devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Ubuntu compatible with my hardware?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430551/is-ubuntu-compatible-with-my-hardware)

Answer (score 8):

I can confirm that it works with Ubuntu 16.04LTS. If you use the unifying receiver that came with the mouse it will already be paired when you plug it in. If you wish to pair to a pre-existing unifying receiver you should install [Solaar](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/), which provides basic control over pairing, and limited configuration options for some Logitech peripherals.

I used a pre-existing unifying receiver, and paired my MX Master to it using Solaar.  It does detect battery strength, but does not provide configuration of gestures, dpi, scrolling, etc.  The mouse's standard configuration seems to be fine, except that it would really be nice if I could configure the hidden thumb button to switch workspaces for me. The hidden thumb button creates a key sequence, so I guess I could map that sequence within Linux to do workspace swaps.

Anyway, aside from minimal support for configurability, it works great.

I have also paired it using Bluetooth. Doing so required installing blueman and trusting the device.

As an update: The MX Master continues to work under Ubuntu 17.04 just as it did under Ubuntu 16.xx versions. I've also been using it under 18.xx and 19.xx.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741330/how-do-i-get-logitech-mx-anywhere-2-to-work-in-16-04-bluetooth-smart/769095#769095) is supposed to be for a MX Anwhere 2, but it worked for my MX Master.

Open `bluetoothctl`, then:

```
[bluetooth]# power off
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[Arc Touch Mouse SE]# trust
[Arc Touch Mouse SE]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[Arc Touch Mouse SE]# pair
[Arc Touch Mouse SE]# unblock
[Arc Touch Mouse SE]# power off
[bluetooth]# power on
```

Comment: KDE Neon 5.24 (Ubuntu 20.04). It was impossible to connect properly via KDE applet. But bluetoothctl did the trick. It's weird, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I have connected my Logitech MX Master via bluetooth using blueman-applet.

```
$ sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Then open it:

```
$ blueman-applet
```

If you have mouse on the list, remove, scan again and connect it.
That's how i fixed it after hours of searching on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

its works on ubuntu 18.04 i use hcitool to find my logitech M590 mac address

> hcitool lescan

then gatttool to get mouse visible

> gatttool -i hci0 [xx.xx.xx ... mac address] -I

https://ericasberry.com/blog/2016/09/30/pairing-a-logitech-mx-master-mouse-with-ubuntu-16-04-using-bluetooth/

Comment: It partially works for me by making my MX Ergo discoverable in blueman, but this is was enough to pair device. :-) Many thanks!