# Bluetooth mouse lag -- Precision 5510 -- MX Anywhere 2 -- 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, bluetooth

I have an MX anywhere 2. After some effort, I managed to pair it (over bluetooth) to my Dell Precision 5510

(see https://askubuntu.com/a/769095/647310)

Now, when I'm using this mouse, it always starts lagging: the cursor becoming slightly jumpy. I never have this problem with a USB mouse.

The problem is not related to wifi and bluetooth coexistence (as suggested in many related threads): it also occurs when wifi is disabled.

My kernel version is 4.10.0-40-generic

This mouse works fine in Windows. It would be nice to also be able to use it in Ubuntu.

Does anyone have ideas on how to get this working properly?

**UPDATE** It might be related to bluetooth-wifi coexist. I seem to experience more bluetooth lag when wifi traffic is heavy. However, disabling coexist, or playçng around with that parameter in `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` does not seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

Tried setting it up on Ubuntu 18.04 and happily (surprisingly, if I'm honest), it worked without any adjustments. True plug and play :-)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a power save issue, your computer is probably trying to save power by turning off the bluetooth adapter. 
I would solve this using powertop, an apt package for monitoring power usage and optimising features. We can use this to remove a power optimisation. 
We can begin by installing powertop:

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
```

once this is finished, we can run powertop b simply typing

```
sudo powertop
```

Press `tab` until you reach tunable and find your bluetooth adapter.
Press `enter` so this displays `bad`. 
Finally press `esc` to exit powertop.

Comment: I don't get this working. Whey I press enter on "Bluetooth device interface status " I get ```sh: 1: /usr/sbin/hciconfig: not found
                                     System is not available```. Also: all other bluetooth-related things are already at ```bad```

Comment: A reboot usually fixes this issue for me.

Comment: Tried that, but doesn't work here.

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling powertop