# Logitech MX Anywhere 2S bluetooth connection problem

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, logitech, mint

I'm currently having an issue with my connection with the MX Anywhere 2S via bluetooth. [Currently running LM18.3]

I seem to have successfully connected the mouse, through an attempt of multiple solutions (the most successful being this https://askubuntu.com/a/769095/804661)

The connection and pairing process all seemed to work, but in a weird way.

The mouse only works when I have it held upright (with the pairing LED blinking and holding in sight). I assume this has something to do with it being in a certain mode when held in this position, and successfully gaining connection through that. But as soon as I place it down, the connection is gone - it goes into another mode.

I have also tried to trace the issue with hcidump, but it seems like it is just working as expected when held upright, then disconnects when placed down.

And this is the info of the device in bluetoothctl

```
Name: MX Anywhere 2S
Alias: MX Anywhere 2S
Appearance: 0x03c2
Icon: input-mouse
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: no
LegacyPairing: no
.
.
.
Modalias: usb:v046DpB01Ad0003
```

(Device is currently not connected)

I can't seem to find anyone with this specific problem. So any help will be appreciated.