# No Bluetooth Found in settings on Ubuntu 16.04, but BT mouse works

Tags: bluetooth

When I open BT control panel in options it says:

" No Bluetooth Found. Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth "

My BT mouse still works. Which I configured following: [741330](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741330/how-do-i-get-logitech-mx-anywhere-2-to-work-in-16-04-bluetooth-smart/769095#769095).

```
bluetoothctl
```

Seems to operate as normal.

Any suggestions to fix this issue? (Want to connect my headphones)

Comment: I would use bluetoothctl to connect to the headphones

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jeremy31. The only issue I got with that is that my headphones only support one BT connection, which makes switching between devices a hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue:

```
sudo apt install unity-control-center
```

For some reason i had previously installed gnome-control-center

Now BT settings are available.

Comment: Thank you! This worked on my asus zenbook with ubuntu 16.04. About the 15th thing I tried.