# Logitech MX ANYWHERE 2 and Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

So I can't make it work, I found this: https://ericasberry.com/blog/2016/09/30/pairing-a-logitech-mx-master-mouse-with-ubuntu-16-04-using-bluetooth/

[Ubuntu 15.10, logitech mx anywhere mouse pairs but doesn't do anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695446/ubuntu-15-10-logitech-mx-anywhere-mouse-pairs-but-doesnt-do-anything)

and this: [Ubuntu 15.10, logitech mx anywhere mouse pairs but doesn't do anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695446/ubuntu-15-10-logitech-mx-anywhere-mouse-pairs-but-doesnt-do-anything)

But still can't make it work.

When I type this command, I'm getting:

$ hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1 Can't set Simple Pairing mode on hci0: Network is down (100)

Answer (score 0):

If you dual-boot with Windows, pair the mouse in Windows, using the Logitech Unifying software. Also configure the mouse speed settings, etc. in the Mouse settings panel. It'll remember these setting when you boot back into Ubuntu.

http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/unifying/downloads#windowsPnlBar
http://support.logitech.com/en_us/category/mice-and-pointers#1main-a

In Ubuntu, you can install `Solaar` and try some of the pairing and configuration there.

https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/

Comment: Solaar doesn't offer configuration options for the mouse

Comment: @hellocatfood Solaar DOES offer some configuration options for some mice, but not all. I never said that it did. That's no reason to down vote my answer.

Comment: @hellocatfood see https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/devices.html for a short list of mice that Solaar CAN configure.

Comment: You're right that this mouse is supported for pairing via Solaar. However, using that tool there are no configuration options, which is what the down vote was for. Secondly, I cannot remove the vote as it was cast nearly a day ago.

Comment: @hellocatfood I clearly provided means to configure ANY mouse using the Logitech Windows software, links provided. Those settings will carry over to Ubuntu. For those that want a Ubuntu solution, Solaar is the only way to pair mice/keyboards, with configuration ability for some options on some mice/keyboards. You clearly need to reconsider how you use the down vote option in the future. My answer clearly answered the original poster's question. You change the down vote by clicking on the up vote arrow.