# Bluetooth Mouse Pairs But Doesn't Work

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, 16.04

Just did a clean install of 16.04 and my Logitech MX Master won't work. I even tried to use blueman to no avail.

Anyone get it working? I used blueman to get it working on 15.

Thanks in advance!

---

Contents of /var/lib/bluetooth///info

```
[General]
Name=MX Master
Appearance=0x03c2
AddressType=static
SupportedTechnologies=LE;
Trusted=false
Blocked=false
Services=00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00010000-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d;

[DeviceID]
Source=2
Vendor=1133
Product=45074
Version=20

[ConnectionParameters]
MinInterval=6
MaxInterval=9
Latency=44
Timeout=216
```

Comment: Does the mouse connect?  Are you running a power indicator (bug 1098959)?  Does your linkkey appear in /var/lib/bluetooth/<host bt addr>/<mouse bt addr>/info?

Comment: @ubfan1 It 'pairs', and the mouse thinks it's connected, but it doesn't do anything. Don't think I have a power indicator, and no linkkey... see contents above in my edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logitech MX Anywhere 2 mouse pairs but doesn't do anything](http://askubuntu.com/questions/636712/logitech-mx-anywhere-2-mouse-pairs-but-doesnt-do-anything)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using the hciconfig answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/660918/534356

Ironically I tried this before and it didn't work... but after re-installing Ubuntu 16 this did solve my problem!

Thanks @Tobi

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the equivalent linkkey paragraph (use the Key your mouse has) to the info file and change the "Trusted" to true.

```
[LinkKey]
Key=532EE33E7E50E79AB350554D63226EA1
Type=4
PINLength=0
```

The trick is to find the key.  It may be dug out of the Microsoft registry if you can pair the mouse on a Windows macnine, or on another linux machine.  Older Ubuntu (bluez4) will have the keys in a file like /var/lib/bluetooth//linkkeys.

First try changing the "Trusted" and adding a linkkey with a bogus key like DEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEF or any random hex value.  Then remove the device from the pairing list and re-pair it.  Hopefully the new key will be inserted and used to let the mouse work.  Blueman has a trust button, try that if you didn't already.

Comment: A attempted the bogus key, after re-pairing it removed the whole LinkKey section from the file. I'll see if I can pair it with another computer and get the linkkey