# Bluetooth Mouse Pairs and Connects But Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, 16.10

[Is there way to achieve a better experience with the Bluetooth driver or an alternative driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870394/is-there-way-to-achieve-a-better-experience-with-the-bluetooth-driver-or-an-alte/870405?noredirect=1#comment1349146_870405)

You can see what I did, updated the firmware. Mouse works fine in Windows still. Now in Ubuntu, I forget the mouse, re-pair, it shows both paired and connected, and registers no clicks nor movement.

It's not like [Logitech MX Anywhere 2 mouse pairs but doesn't do anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636712/logitech-mx-anywhere-2-mouse-pairs-but-doesnt-do-anything/660918#660918) because it shows Type = Mouse.

01/29/17 
The plot thickens:
I got a brand new USB mouse. One of the buttons controls volume, so I know it's connected and somewhat working. However, it doesn't click nor point. In xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer, it has XExtensionPointer next to it, and it's showing up in the list of devices. Maybe this helps diagnose the problem?

Comment: Does the mouse show in the battery indicator?  May be bug 1098959, Bluetooth Battery Indicator Interferes with Bluetooth Mouse Moves.

Comment: The mouse does show in the battery indicator. The mouse has always shown in the battery indicator, and worked. It is only after updating firmware that mouse doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.10, and it still works and always worked on the same machine/bluetooth device in Windows. Is there any way to specifically test whether that bug is the problem? I don't really see anything specific about that bug. Like, how do I know whether the battery indicator is interfering with mouse moves, or if the battery indicator is existing and NOT interfering with mouse moves?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, run `sudo hcidump` and see if moving the mouse produces output (even if the cursor does not move).  If it does, add yourself to the bug #1098959 (question "does this affect me?" in upper left corner).

Try the suggested solutions, reboot with Bluetooth off, kill the powerd process, start Bluetooth, run without a battery in laptop to suppress the title bar battery notification (may be some power options to set too).

And finally if all else fails, just change your mouse.  Only some mice have this problem.  My generic BT mouse had the problem, but a Microsoft Sculpt Comfort does not (and it does not display any mouse battery in the indicator either).

Comment: The mouse does not produce output by moving it around and clicking. It does do some lines of input when the mouse connects/disconnects.


I ordered a wired mouse out of frustration. But this is really poor user experience. Something Ubuntu really needs to tackle to make Ubuntu worth using. Bluetooth connected devices are essential to users' personal  computing experiences.