# Logitech M720 mouse pairs and connects but doesn't do anything

Tags: 18.04, mouse, bluetooth, 19.04, bluez

I have read [Logitech MX Anywhere 2 mouse pairs but doesn't do anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636712/logitech-mx-anywhere-2-mouse-pairs-but-doesnt-do-anything/660918#660918) and tried using `bluetoothctl` to get my M720 set up. It's not working, to summarize.

I've also got an M557 which *does* work, so I can compare and contrast the reported settings. Here's what `bluetoothctl` reports for the non-working M720:

```
Device FF:1F:22:D6:07:67 (random)
    Name: M720 Triathlon
    Alias: M720 Triathlon
    Appearance: 0x03c2
    Icon: input-mouse
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00010000-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d)
    Modalias: usb:v046DpB015d0009
```

(The M720 has 3 channels, so it looks like 3 different devices; that's the "channel 1" information. The others have a device ID ending in 68 and 69.) Note that the device is paired, trusted, and connected.

Now here's the `info` reported for the working M557:

```
Device 34:88:5D:B0:42:C9 (public)
    Name: Bluetooth Mouse M557
    Alias: Bluetooth Mouse M557
    Class: 0x00000580
    Icon: input-mouse
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Service Discovery Serve.. (00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device... (00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v046DpB010d1002
```

The interesting differences to me are that instead of `(random)` in the header line, it says `(public)`; the M557 has a "Class" entry, while the M720 does not; and the UUID section is significantly different.

Furthermore, when I turn the M557 off and then back on, I get kernel log messages about a new `/devices/` entry, and I get no kernel messages at all when I power on the M720.

So it seems to me that while the Bluetooth infrastructure is "seeing" the M720, it doesn't pass it on to the HID system as a new input device for some reason. I don't know enough to know what that reason might be.

Oh and I'm running 4.15.0-60-generic, 18.04. Bluez is version 5.48-0ubuntu3.1. Laptop is a Lenovo X1 Carbon (6th Gen).

With `btmon` I can see activity from the M720, so I'm pretty sure that the mouse itself is in working condition. I can pair it with my phone (ZTE Axon 7) and it works fine.

---

Updated to 19.04, same deal.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `hciconfig`.
Take a look to this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/660918/1001175), it seems to fix a similar issue.

Other info :

- hciconfig doc : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/hciconfig.1.html
- hcitool doc : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/hcitool.1.html
- random vs public addresses : https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/27012/how-to-distinguish-between-random-and-public-gap-addresses

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've looked at that information. I don't think I've got a Bluetooth problem; the mouse does connect and pair. The problem seems to be that the system does not recognize the device as an input device. As I wrote in the question, a working bt mouse results in the kernel logging "hey there's a new input device" message or two, but the non-working mouse doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with a windows PC. Whenever I press the button 1, 2, and 3 in sequence and then hold button 3 for a few seconds, it reconnects to computer and works again.