# Connecting a Bluetooth 4.0 LE mouse (Microsoft mobile mouse 3600)

Tags: mouse, 15.10, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect a [Microsoft Bluetooth Mobile Mouse 3600](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/mice/bluetooth-mobile-mouse-3600/pn7-00001) in Ubuntu 15.10.

I first tried connecting through `unity-control-center`. This would discover the device, but fail to connect every time. On further research, it seems it's not possible to connect to a LE (low energy) device this way.

So I tried it with CLI tools. I can get this far:

```
$ sudo hcitool lescan
LE Scan ...
F2:C2:08:8A:DD:10 BluetoothMouse3600
F2:C2:08:8A:DD:10 (unknown)
sudo gatttool -I
[                 ][LE]> connect F2:C2:08:8A:DD:10 random
Attempting to connect to F2:C2:08:8A:DD:10
Connection successful
[F2:C2:08:8A:DD:10][LE]>
```

So it seems the mouse is connected. However, it does not seem to be working as a mouse, at least when I move it, the pointer does not move. Also, `hcidump` does not show any activity when I move the mouse.

Is there something more I need to do to get it recognized as a mouse? Any more troubleshooting steps I might take?

Comment: Thank you for the post. I have the same problem for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Therefore i've adapted the question -- to avoid forum redundancy. Hope it is fine for you. Good day :)

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/646433/microsoft-designer-mouse-bluetooth-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts?rq=1) (answer from Chris McCormick) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

After a few false starts I have Microsoft Bluetooth Mobile Mouse 3600 working on a Dell XPS with Ubuntu 14.04.  I took the advice in [Logitech MX Master Mouse pairs, but won't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621860/logitech-mx-master-mouse-pairs-but-wont-work/660666#660666)
and installed Bluez 5.41

Using bluetoothctl I was able to pair and 'trust' the mouse.
On my first attempt the mouse would work fine for a few minutes, then I'd need to power off and power on bluetooth using hciconfig hci0 down; hciconfig hci0 up

Eventually I figured out that I had two entries for the mouse in /var/lib/bluetooth/XX:YY:ZZ.....   Once I wiped out the contents of that directory and started over, pair, etc. all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Dell Inspiron 5557, running Ubuntu 16.04. I have detected, paired and I'm using this mouse, without any package or configuration.

The only trick that I really needed was to push and hold the power button of the mouse some seconds (It turns on a green light behind the mouse) and detect and pair the mouse with blueman. I just was able to do this after use this trick.

Comment: After dabbling with command line for a few hours,  this (installing blueman and adding the mouse there) worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Tks.