# Can't connect my Logitech MX Master

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, logitech

Hi my problem is quite the same like here **[Logitech MX Master Mouse pairs, but won't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621860/logitech-mx-master-mouse-pairs-but-wont-work)**.

but when i typ in

> hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1

my Terminal puts out

> Can't set Simple Pairing mode on hci0: Operation not permitted (1)

hciconfig -a says:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
BD Address: 20:16:D8:85:9C:21  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
RX bytes:2810 acl:28 sco:0 events:156 errors:0
TX bytes:5658 acl:28 sco:0 commands:121 errors:0
Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0xd8 0x7f 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
Name: 'TimsAsus'
Class: 0x1c010c
Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
Device Class: Computer, Laptop
HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x102
LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x1
Manufacturer: Atheros Communications, Inc. (69)
```

Comment: My MX Master mouse (or maybe it's the Pro I get the two versions mixed up) works perfectly out of the box with the Unifying Receiver which doesn't use Bluetooth but rather IR. It might help if you listed your bluetooth settings in your question too. I know bluetooth has created problems for many.

Comment: How can i get my bluetooth settings?

Comment: I've never used my mouse with bluetooth, only with the Unifying Receivers IR mode. So I can't help in the BT area. Didn't you turn on bluetooth before using it?

Comment: Yeah it's the same problem like in the linked thread. But i cant solve my Problem with their solution, because i get the Error "Can't set Simple Pairing mode on hci0: Operation not permitted (1)". Now I am also using the Unifying Reveiver but i hate it at my Laptop because i only have 2 USB Ports. But thanks for the Tip =)

Comment: You can get a tiny 4 port hub for 5 bucks on eBay.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago from this question but maybe someone will read this nowadays.

I was getting the same "Can't set Simple Pairing mode on hci0: Operation not permitted (1)" after a long search and did not found nothing about it I had the happy idea of make "sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1" maybe I could not found any information about because it is too obvious :)!

Hope this will util for someone.